# Appending nested JSON data into columns using Python

Tags: python, json, dataframe, parsing, python-requests

I am trying to get the output of a JSON response into a easier to read table with  column headers. I am running into the problem of trying to access the specific JSON  information. Here is what I have so far

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = requests.get('https://apitest.com/api/scanners',auth=('', ''))
r = json.loads(url.content)
a = r['items']
```

My response is in this format [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A5n0.png)

I want to be able to append this information with the information of scanner name, antenna number and the last scan date, so I can eventually  create a dataframe with the column headers

```
d = []
for h in a:
    d.append(
            { 'ScannerName': h['name'],
              'AntennaNumber':h['antennae']['antenna'],
              'LastScanDate': h['antennae']['lastScanDate']
                        }
            )
```

I receive a "**TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**" at this point. I wanted to know if anybody has any suggestions on a possible solution or if I need to approach this in a different way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data type of **'antennae'** is a **list**, that's why you can not get value by using the key.

You must **iterate** the 'antennae' list and only then you'll be able to get the **'antenna'** and **'lastScanDate'** key.

Probably this would work as you expected:

```
d = []
for h in a:
   scanner = {
      'ScannerName' : h['name'],
      'AntennaNumber' : [],
      'LastScanDate' : []
   }

   for antennae in h['antennae']:
      scanner['AntennaNumber'].append(antennae['antenna'])
      scanner['LastScanDate'].append(antennae['lastScanDate'])

   d.append(scanner)

print(d)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was under the impression this was my problem but was unsure of the syntax and which way to go , when I try to recreate this I only receive one scanner name,the last one. Is  there another step for me to iterate so I can return them all?

Comment: @TreyLaMonte I think it's not a mistake. If you pay attention to your screenshot, you can find out that your first record's 'antennea' is empty. Thus you will have some records with name and empty 'antennea'.

Comment: You are right, I am using Juypter Notebook and I split the cells accidentally separating the for loops thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get almost where you want to be just with plain Pandas dataframe:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import requests
url = 'https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544/positions?timestamps=1593535000,1593538000'
response = requests.get(url)
r = json.loads(response.content)
pd.DataFrame(r)
```

(out comes a table).

To get the data from inner levels of nesting, I'd go with `df.apply()` with lambda functions!

Comment: I am going to explore this option also, I am fairly new to Python  so I will have to fiddle around with defining the functions, this gets me really close to what I am trying to accomplish.